# Turtlebot disconnects when additional /dev/ttyUSB port is active

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying out the Turtlebot stack under Electric (beta).  So far everything works great including the follower application.  Next I want to control two Dynamixel AX-12 servos that I have attached to the Kinect for pan and tilt.  The Create is on port /dev/ttyUSB1 and my USB2Dynamixel controller is on /dev/ttyUSB0 and I am using the dynamixel_motor package to control the servos.

When I launch the Turtlebot using the minimal.launch file, everything comes up fine on /dev/ttyUSB1.  But as soon as I launch the dynamixel_motor controllers (which comes up fine on /dev/ttyUSB0), I get the following error in the Turtlebot launch window:

```
Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. Wrong data length.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.[turtlebot_node-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/patrick/.ros/log/28a03a10-bb09-11e0-bde5-00271017076c/turtlebot_node-3*.log
respawning...
[turtlebot_node-3] restarting process
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [9174]
```

This block then just keeps repeating indefinitely.

Has anyone else experienced something similar?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10773/turtlebot-disconnects-when-additional-/dev/ttyusb-port-is-active/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-07-31**:
Thanks Alaina--that did the trick!  If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it as the correct answer.

**Comment by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) on 2011-07-31**:
Have you tried setting your udev rules to make the SCI port /dev/ttyUSB0 and your USB2Dynamixel controller /dev/ttyUSB1? I have a Logitech webcam running on /dev/ttyUSB1 with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried setting your udev rules to make the SCI port /dev/ttyUSB0 and your USB2Dynamixel controller /dev/ttyUSB1? I have a Logitech webcam running on /dev/ttyUSB1 with no problems.

The Turtlebot software is looking for the Create on ttyUSB0. You can change that in the launch files, but I prefer to mess with less. :)

---

Originally posted by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) with karma: 121 on 2011-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-08-01**:
Actually, I did set the Create port to /dev/ttyUSB1 in the launch file and it connected to that port fine but I still ran into the disconnect problem when the USB2Dynamixel is on port /dev/ttyUSB0.  So I am wondering if there might be some other place in the Turtlebot code where USB0 is hard coded.  In any event, your udev solution works fine for now.  Thanks!

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2013-05-28**:
Could one of you guys post here the udev files you created? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got same problem - iCreate is no longer accessible on /dev/ttyUSB0. Could you please provide your solution on how you have change launch configuration? I've search settings for USB in minimal_launch of the turtlebot_bringup stack but didn't find anything useful.

Another question - is it better to change launch configuration of the turtlebot or change port settings in ubuntu itself? Let's say somewhere in other packages there would be hard coded port  ttyUSB0 but I had changed it on 1, so I would create new problem for myself. What would be the best solution in this case? Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) with karma: 131 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-28**:
Definitively udev rules is the good way, as you can fix port names. You can also provide meaningful names to your ports, as /dev/turtlebot, /dev/aduino, etc...